# Javascript, postMessage to Iframe

Tags: javascript

```
<body onload="onload();">

function onload()
{
    document.onkeypress = function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault(); // Prevent any default browser behaviour.
        console.log('send: '+e);
        document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage ('Hello Treehouse!', '*my*');
    }
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { console.log('get: '+event); }, false);
}
</script>
```

I want to forward keypresses to iframe but so far it doesnt work, iframe doesnt receive the messages

Comment: check [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) about postMessage, is it similar to yours?

Comment: I cant see the difference

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to bind the event listening within the same window as the sender, when you actually need that within the iFrame itself.

i.e. within your iFrame have this code:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { console.log('get: '+event); }, false);
</script>
```